# Base Analogue of `arrange()` in Pipelines

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Pipelines using `dplyr::filter()` and `dplyr::mutate()` can often be replaced with base-R equivalents `subset()` and `transform()`, a possible benefit in package development. Is there any direct base-R analogue of `arrange()` that can used in a base-R pipeline?

Of course there is `order()`, but usage in a pipeline is not as clear as `arrange()`. Below is the best I came up with, but it's not lovely:

```
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = sample(100, 5))
dat

library(dplyr)
dat |> 
  filter(x > 2) |> 
  mutate(z = y / x) |> 
  arrange(z)

# Using base-R only
dat |> 
  subset(x > 2) |> 
  transform(z = y / x) |> 
  {\(d) d[order(d$z), ]}()
```

Result:

```
  x  y     z
4 4  1  0.25
5 5 34  6.80
3 3 39 13.00
```

Comment: You might be out of luck, unless you consider `(\(d) d[with(d, order(v1, v2, v3)), ])()` to be meaningfully different.

Comment: `arrange2 <- function(data, ...) {data[eval.parent(substitute(with(data, order(...)))), , drop = FALSE]}` would also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a good base equivalent to `dplyr::arrange()`. We could write our own function which would behave similar to `substitute()`, lets call it `organize()`:

```r
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = sample(100, 5))

organize <- function (df, ..., na.last = TRUE, decreasing = FALSE,
                      method = c("auto", "shell", "radix"), drop = FALSE) {
  method <- match.arg(method)
  dots <- eval(substitute(alist(...)))
  exprs <- lapply(dots, FUN = \(e) eval(e, df, parent.frame())) 
  arg_ls <- c(exprs,
              na.last = na.last,
              decreasing = decreasing,
              method = method
              )
  df[do.call("order", arg_ls), , drop = drop]
}

dat |>
  subset(select = 2) |>
  organize(y)
#>    y
#> 4  1
#> 1 14
#> 5 34
#> 3 39
#> 2 68

mtcars |>
  organize(gear, -mpg) |>
  head()
#>                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Toyota Corona     21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Pontiac Firebird  19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> Merc 450SL        17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this is a great utility! I've seen `drop` to avoid coercing a single-column data frame to a vector, but what does it do here? Wouldn't the resulting data frame have the same number of rows and columns as the input?

Comment: @nahp:`drop` here does two things. First, it will prevent one-column `data.frame`s to be coerced to atomic vectors by default. Without `drop` using `organize()` on  a one-column `data.frame` would result in an atomic vector. Second, it gives the user the option to actually return a vector when used on a one-column `data.frame`. I'm not so sure if this is needed. We could delete the argument and replace the right hand side `drop` in the last line with `FALSE`.

Comment: I see; I had forgotten that the input might have just one column!